# Flash like Animation ONLY Library for C/C++ (no GUI)

Tags: c++, flash, animation, keyframe

I'm looking for an opensource C/C++ library for managing keyframe or time based animation.

I already have a graphic layer, so it doesn't need to do any drawing, I just want it to manage tweening or interpolation very much like Flash does, specifically:

- Allows multiple objects to be managed in an overall scene or stage.
- Allows me to string together a series of tweens and it figures out the active tween
- Allows me to jump to any frame for my scene, and it tweens or interpolates the values for all objects in the scene.
- Has variable frame rates for playback. e.g. frame_rate = 1 would play at 1 frame/sec.
- And a total nice to have would be if the stage object could save and load it's state ;-)

I've seen lots of stuff out there for managing a single tween or interpolation, but nothing that seems to wrap up the higher level concepts of running a series of tweens end to end, and coordinating that with the concept of an overall timeline, much like Flash does.

Comment: Don't know how much of what you would want to do is in Qt's Animation framework, but they do have one: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/animation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the gameswf library? It is open-source and public domain so you can do whatever you want with it. But that is only if you are willing to use SWF as the container of your animation.

Also gameswf does not depends on flash and is programmed in C++. It can be compiled under Windows, MacOSX and Linux.

[GAMESWF website link](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html)

Edit:

I will also add the Vektrix library. It is licensed under MIT so again completely free and open-source, is GPU-accelerated and well coded and maintained compared to gameswf. However, the rendering frontend for now is only OGRE3D. But i believe it is made to support others as well.

[Vektrix website](http://www.fuse-software.com/vektrix)

Comment: hmmm..... i don't really want to use the SWF format as a container for my animations, but will take a look at GameSWF to see if I can easily rip out the relevant parts.... good thought!

Comment: Since you required tweening or interpolation of animation frames, you are pretty much required to use vector graphics which limits your animation format to SWF or maybe SVG. But i do not know any open-source library supporting SVG animation. However, the best for rendering SVG images is CAIRO.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the GUI part of it isn't relevant for my needs, so that part of it isn't a concern as I already have that addressed!

Comment: Don't let the UI mention misguide you. gameswf uses 3D hardware acceleration opengl/d3d to render vector graphics as triangle very fast. To use it, you derive a class from their render_handler object which you can then draw anywhere, including in-memory texture for compositing or drawing the animation frames anywhere on-screen or on 3d objects. Anyway... just wanted to make sure you do not see it as UI only. Up to you :)  Also if you find an alternative, please let us know as i am interested too. Thanks